# how to copy (resized) camera image and use it back in Processing

Tags: image, camera, resize, processing

I have a small bit of code to get the camera:

```java
void setup() {
    if (cam.available() == false) {
        cam.start();
    }
}

void draw() {
    if (cam.available() == true) {
         cam.read();
    }
    image(cam, w/2, h/2, w, 480.0/640.0*w); // resized according to size()
}
```

If I use cam.get(), the image is not resized, it keeps the camera resolution.

Is there any solution to get the "resized" camera image?

I tried

```java
big = copy(cam, int(w/2), int(h/2), int(w), int(480/640*w), 0, 0, int(w), int(h));
```

but it doesn't seem to work (same for cam.copy(...).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the video library and `cam` is a `Capture`, then I would expect these methods to work. `Capture` extends `PImage`, so you should be able to copy and resize it.

So the first thing I'd check is what values you're passing into these functions. The `println()` function is your best friend.

Or try passing hardcoded values so you know what to expect:

```java
image(cam, 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

If that really doesn't work, then as a worst case scenario you could use the [`Capture.get()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_get_.html) function to get the pixels yourself, then do the resizing manually. I really don't think you'll have to do that though.